# How do I post data to a SQL Server database from a HTML input field in umbraco

Tags: html, sql-server, forms, umbraco

I have an input text box which will be used for newsletter sign ups. I want to store these emails in a table in a SQL Server database.

I have the database set up, I just don't know how I would post the data to it.

By the way the site is set up using Umbraco if that makes any difference.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a pretty broad question and not a simple "how to" kind of thing with a simple answer.

Comment: well I have never used any amount of code to store an item in a database

Comment: To be hones i have no idea where to start

Comment: Well it is written in C# so your code needs to be in the C# code behind. https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=c%23%20insert%20into%20sql

Comment: The only problem is  that i have no experience in visual studio and c#. could you please help

Comment: Teaching you how to write proper queries in C# is way beyond the scope of an online forum. If you look at the google link I posted the very first return has a good example of how to do it.

Comment: I'm comfortable with database queries and such. I'm an IT Technician whose roles include database management server set-ups and maintaining and deploying websites and also building sites with CSS html an JS. Does know one have a little snippet for umbraco where one text field posts to a database? doesn't have to be anything fancy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have no experience with Umbraco or c# programming a MailChimp umbraco package might maybe help:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/mailchimp4umbraco

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm fine when it comes to writing XSLT'S and using data sets. but only for building content pages. Could a Razor form be hacked down to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes it is!  If you start your Razor with @if(IsPost) { ... }  you can launch whatever c# code you want.  e.g. call a database or whatever you want.  If you can do XSLT, than you can do razor (and some c# too).  One more thing, stackoverflow is Q&A, if you want a forum, try http://our.umbraco.org/

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a good approach, it can be done using a Razor file.  I suggest you read this blog post to get a better understanding of how you SHOULD do it: http://creativewebspecialist.co.uk/2013/07/16/umbraco-petapoco-to-store-blog-comments/

Umbraco uses [petapoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) under the covers.  PetaPoco is a light weight database query/update tool.  So you can use this to access the database table.  If you don't know petapoco, this is a good time to digg in.  :-)

You can add c# code inside your razor script.  Everything between @{ ... } can be plain old c# code.

Below, we start with checking if the pages has been posted back.  If it is, we run some code and return.  If not, the rest of the page will be rendered.

```
@{
  if(IsPost) {
    var myNewValue = Request.Form["field1"];

    var db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;  
    db.Update("articles", "article_id", new { title="New title" }, 123);

    <div>save success</div>  

    return;
  }
}
<form method="POST">
  <input name="field1">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Although it works (and I have done it multiple times), I don't advise you do use the code above because:

- This is a very quick and dirty solution.
- It doesn't follow best practices.
- And it will not work with multiple forms on the same page.

(Although the last objection could be circumvented by adding a hidden field to check which form you submit...)